# How to setup phpmyadmin?

Tags: apache-httpd, phpmyadmin

My machine is running arch linux.

if I uncomment this line in my **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf** :

```
   Include conf/extra/phpmyadmin.conf
```

phpmyadmin takes over my document root and when I go to `localhost` in my browser it just opens the phpmyadmin/index.php page and I no longer can access my projects in my DocumentRoot

but if I comment the above line in the server config, `localhost` opens my DocumentRoot and I can see all the php files and directories/projects  I have created.

so for now I enable phpmyadim only to do the mysql things I want to do then disable it.

**My question** is : how can I enable phpmyadmin without it taking over my server  ?

this is the **/etc/httpd/conf/extra/phpmyadmin.conf** file :

```
<VirtualHost pma.localhost:80>
       ServerAdmin phpmyadmin@apache.com
       DocumentRoot "/usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin"
       ServerName pma.localhost
       ServerAlias pma.localhost
       ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/pma.localhost-error_log"

       <Directory "/usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin">
           DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
           AllowOverride All
           Options FollowSymlinks
           Require all granted
       </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>

Alias /phpmyadmin "/usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin"
<Directory "/usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Options FollowSymlinks
    Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration looks strange to me but I've never worked with arch. I would suggest:

**Method 1 (Reinstall):**

1. ***Backup your MySQL Database!***
2. `pacman -Rns phpmyadmin`
3. `pacman -S phpmyadmin`

Be sure to follow the installer steps on screen!

**Method 2 (tinker with the configs):**

1. Setup a FQHN for this machine
2. Make sure you actually setup VirtualHosts (your other projects) via
   `sites-available/siteXY.conf` and `a2ensite siteXY.conf`
3. Test the configuration made in 2.) to verify you can access at least
   two different sites in your browser (www.projectXY-1.intranet / www.project-XY-2.intranet)
4. Remove (comment or make backup before!) the `VirtualHost-Section` in
   your `phpmyadmin.conf`

2.) and 3.) are to make sure you the cause doesn't lie in a misconfigured apache2.

[On the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/phpMyAdmin) you can also find examples how the `phpmyadmin.conf` should look like and other information.

Comment: I used the configuration provided in arch wiki and its working fine . I don't know how I missed it the first time. thanks